# Which is better : to group records in a sql server stored procedure or to group in rdlc report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, rdlc

Which is better : to group records in a SQL Server stored procedure or to group in rdlc report ?

Comment: Better to do the work in the database.

Comment: Sometimes you can only get the functionality you desire in the Report itself, but GROUPing in the database first is much faster, cleaner, betterer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in the database unless you need the details rows available to allow drill down in the report itself.

This means that the resultset passed back to the report will potentially be much smaller and SQL Server will likely have better algorithms and more information about the source data to do the grouping efficiently.